# Meaning of specific passage of corporate text, "processes are managed in customized in-house training"

Tags: phrase-meaning

BMW’s active management development
process involves three components: corporate development programs (for
example on culture, e-commerce), professional development programs (for
example skills such as conflict management) and dialogue (communication
skills, working cross-functionally and so on). **These processes are managed
in customized in-house training, facilitated by freelance trainers and business
school faculty**. In addition, special programs help develop future leaders.

I can't understand the bold part completely. Please explain it to me in an easier way.

Comment: What part of the section in bold can you not understand? Please be specific, as your question is currently unclear. Please also include what research you've done and what you found. For further guidance, see [ask].

Comment: Please fix the typo in the title

Answer (score 1):

The whole paragraph is typical 'business speak' - I'm not surprised you are having difficulty.

These processes ---> the programs mentioned earlier

are managed ----> are taught

in customized in-house training ----> in training that that is specifically designed to suit BMW and takes place at BMW

facilitated by freelance trainers ----> taught by self-employed teachers

and business school faculty ----> and academic professors/teachers who normally teach students at a business school

Comment: Just wondering as a non-native speaker - isn't "in-house training, facilitated by freelance trainers and business school" kind of self-contradictory?

Comment: @JulesCocovin, it probably means that, although the 'trainers' come from outside the organisation, they come to the organisation to provide the training within it (in a form that is 'customized' to its specific circumstances).